# FFT of R2R DAC in LTSpice

Tags: fft

I designed a 6-bit current-mode R2R DAC in LTSpice. This is the output spectrum with a 500kHz input sinusoid to an ideal ADC (running at 10MHz clock) which feeds directly into the DAC. Vin is input to ADC, Vout is output of DAC

[image]

The output FFT spectrum looks like this:
[image]

I have a few questions about this:

1. **How do I determine the SNR and SNDR of this?** Usually when I use Cadence Virtuoso for this kind of stuff, it gives me that output.
2. Secondly, does my FFT spectrum seem okay? I know there is a lot of posts about LTSpice putting junk at the end of the FFT. I have tried my best to follow all the tips given by others on how to reduce it. (plotwinsize, etc.)

Comment: See [this](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/371179/95619). When you posted the question, didn't this, or other, similar ones, come in the list of suggestions? As for SNR&co, you measure, then calculate, there's no automatic tool for that. One way to do it would be to subtract a known fundamental.

Comment: @aconcernedcitizen As I mentioned, I have followed tips given by others including that post. It has reduced it and my question was does it look okay at this point?